# Enforcing lock screen after idle time

Tags: security

I have long time troubles with enforcing lock screen after idle time. I set the policy as mentioned above - Interactive logon: Machine inactivity limit. It doesn't  work for me, at all. Every policy concerning screen saver is Not Configured. I tested it on several PC's with win10 and servers with Win2016. But without success.
Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enforcing lock screen after idle time via GPO](https://serverfault.com/questions/79418/enforcing-lock-screen-after-idle-time-via-gpo)